Excel Formula search criteria with a cell reference and wildcards (*) does not include the results where the cell only contains the reference string
I specify a SUMIFS formula that checks for a criteria using a reference.
For this example, i use =SUMIFS(B:B; C:C; "*" & F3 & "*") (F4 in the second example). Provided picture shows the result of 2 formulas that calculate the SUM in column E.

I cant figure out why the SUM for CRITERIA 2030 does not add up to $15 and also why the SUM for CRITERIA 2031 does not add up to $55.
The use of wildcards (*) specifically states that it checks for any length including 0 characters.
Currently i work around this problem by using =SUM(SUMIFS(B:B; C:C; "*" & F3 & "*"); SUMIFS(B:B; C:C; F3)) but it does not sit right with me.
Any ideas?

Like I said in the comments:

It seems that your criteria is only searching for text values, as 2030 and 2031 are numerical values, they don't show up. I got it working by formatting the cells as text, then editing them (add a space) and reversing the edit (remove the space).

I was too late to edit, but you could just double click or press F2 and enter each cell. However:
I got around this by using FILTER, ISNUMBER and SEARCH:
=SUM(FILTER(B:B;(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F2;C:C)))))



This works brilliantly. Thank you. The previous edit didnt do the trick as the content was also a reference. Hence setting the cell to text would result in formulas of their own. Thank you for the solution!

@RAH ah, I didn't get that from your question, but I put I'll leave it here for future reference. It indeed wouldn't have helped. Glad I could help.

A simple formula works
[E3]=SUM($B$3:$B$5*ISNUMBER(FIND(F3,$C$3:$C$5)))

Fill it down.


How is it going?
